# Is it possible to have multiple valid access tokens with the same client credentials?

Tags: oauth-2.0, wso2, access-token

I have an API set with OAuth2 authentication. A client has subscribe to my API using WSO2.
We don't use refresh tokens. All access tokens expire in 1 hour.

What happens if my client requests 2 access tokens with the same client credentials?
Will the first token be revoked or will both tokens live 1 hour?

Answer (score 7):

When you request a token with client credentials, it will give an access token which is valid for 1 hour. If you again request a token from the token API within that 1 hour period, then it will give the same token. Basically, if there is a valid token, then it will return that. This is the default behavior.

But if you are using the API Store and click on token re-generation, then it will first revoke the token and get you a new access token.

If you want to get two different access tokens for the same client credentials at the same time, then you can use a scope. When there are different scopes in the token request, it will return two different access tokens.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The problem i have  : 
- The second access token is different from the first one
- Around 10 min after i request the second access token, the first one is revoked. 
The solution i want is : if i have 2 requests i want the same access token. Exactly what you describe. 

I will check tomorrow how my WSO2 is set up.

Answer (score 5):

According to [WSO2 docs](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Working+with+Access+Tokens), you can't have more than one access token. What you can do instead is changing the token expiration time to longer than one hour.

> In WSO2 API-M the access token must be unique for the following combinations - CONSUMER_KEY, AUTHZ_USER, USER_TYPE, TOKEN_STATE, TOKEN_STATE_ID and TOKEN_SCOPE. The latter mentioned constraint is defined in the IDN_OAUTH2_ACCESS_TOKEN table. **Therefore, it is not possible to have more than one Access Token for any of the above combinations.**

Comment: Thank you for your answer !

Comment: It is actually possible to have different access tokens simultaneously for the same client, given they have different scopes.