# oAuth2 - Multiple tokens with the same user credentials

Tags: java, oauth

We are calling and in-house API from our software package. Each client site has their own set of oAuth2 keys and secrets.

Our problem is that we want to get a unique token for each user but, with the current implementation, we are getting a unique token for each site (that expires every hour). Since it would be impractical for each user to have his/her own set of credentials, is it possible to get a unique token for each user but still using the same key and secret?

I have seen a post suggesting using the scope but that makes no sense. The scope is there to define user access, not token generation. Besides, I have tested it and it does not work.

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59022460/is-it-possible-to-have-multiple-valid-access-tokens-with-the-same-client-credent][1]

We also cannot use token_expiry since we don't know what the current token is (we do not persist it anywhere).

Comment: I am not entirely sure I understand your question. Normally, there will be a single jwt generated for each login call. This token is then passed along with each request until the user logs out or the token expires. The clients (I suspect resource servers?) should only validate the token and trigger the Authorization Code Flow if necessary. The scope is used to define what information are included within the token and for what actions the token can be use (common scopes are `profile`, `email`, ...).

Comment: @Turning85, oAuth tokens are issues based on your credentials (key & secret) and not per user. If UserA  calls an API he will get TokenX. When UserB calls the same API, he will get the same TokenX because they are using the same credentials. Keys and Secrets are issues on an organization level and not a user level, therefore everybody in the organization will get the same token. We want each user to get a unique token even if they use the same credentials. It would've been nice if one could add something like a device to the token URL which could result in a unique token.

Comment: We are using WSO2 and I just found out that you can add "scope=device_xxxx" to get a unique token per device... now to get it to work...
https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Working+with+Access+Tokens

Answer (score 0):

Use the scope=device_xx from WSO2. Initially my code did not work and it turned out that somebody changed the default ScopeWhitelist on our server to be "device:" instead of "device_". Once changed back to the default, all code worked perfectly.